# Can I Force A ASP.Net Website to Show Time in A Specific Time Zone?

Tags: c#, asp.net, time, timezone

I have a client request that all times be displayed in Pacific Time Zone, regardless of client settings. I'd like to avoid a scenario where I have to call a function for every time display and instead have a single point where I can make the switch.

I'm thinking a custom culture might do the trick, but I wanted to ask before I set off down a potentially blind alley (or miss something trivially easy).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `TimeZone.GetUTCOffset()` and `DateTime.UtcNow()`

Basically get the UTC Time and offset that based on the timezone you are interested in.

Comment: Would that approach need to be applied on each field where a DateTime field was displayed or something I could use on a Master Page and have it cascade down to individual fields? I may be asking for too much, but I was hoping for a DRY solution for the entire site.

Comment: I wonder if Jon Skeet's Noda time library will handle this scenario when it's complete.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the documentation for Daniel's sample:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you store your times in UTC you can convert to whatever you want easily. Michael Brumm has some fairly old code that may help you out with a custom TimeZone. Hard coding an offset will cause issues when DST kicks in.

Note: I haven't used this code on Michael's site.

http://www.michaelbrumm.com/simpletimezone.html

Comment: I'm definitely trying to avoid a hard-coded scenario, so thanks for the reminder!